# Android resource linking failed chat21

Tags: android, api, chat

I am trying to add chat21 API to my project but facing an error "Android resource linking failed"

I have tried looking at resource files for any errors as well as looking as similar posts but none of them helped me in this case

> Android resource linking failed warn: removing resource
>   com.example.bartertrade:string/activity_public_profile_presence_not_available
>   without required default value.
>   /Users/neha/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/bc7291a5f042de9d7c80c9df50272833/res/layout/layout_custom_notification.xml:29:
>   error: resource style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Notification.Title (aka
>   com.example.bartertrade:style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Notification.Title)
>   not found.
>
> error: failed linking file resources.

```html
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/box_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/image">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
          style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Notification.Title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/time"
            android:maxLength="20"
            android:maxLines="1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/time"
           style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Notification.Time"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:gravity="end" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

"Android resource linking failed" this error will delete your R.Java which contains your linking data, it occurs when some error have in the XML file.

Try to find the error on your XML file.

I guess you added `style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Notification.Title"` this , which is not supported.

I am trying to add chat21 API to my project but facing an error "Android resource linking failed"

I have tried looking at resource files for any errors as well as looking as similar posts but none of them helped me in this case

Android resource linking failed warn: removing resource com.example.bartertrade:string/activity_public_profile_presence_not_available without required default value. /Users/neha/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/bc7291a5f042de9d7c80c9df50272833/res/layout/layout_custom_notification.xml:29: error: resource style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Notification.Title (aka **com.example.bartertrade:style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Notification.Title) not found.**

> And you can see that program could not find the that particular thing
>   . When you remove these lines from your XML file. Then your problem
>   will fix.